# How to read a file and update the file at particular line with nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-scripts

I want to create a node script to generate set of folders and file and write some starting code to it like we have cli commands from angular. I have a file called `screen_names.js`, whenever a new screen is created by running command `npm run feature [featureName]`, a folder with some sub folders and files are created inside the feature folder in may application and i want to add and import statement after all others import statements in the file and add an export state after all other export statement in the file.

```
import Input from '../features/Input/containers'
import Segment from '../features/segment/containers'
....
// add an import state here

export {
...,
    Input,
    Segment,
// add export component name here
}
```

How can i read this file and append at appropriate positions and save the file again in javascript.

Comment: What did you try? I see no problem once you know how to read and write files. If you don't know how to use `fs`, consider asking this directly - or checking the manual at least for fundamental Node things.

Comment: i know how to read files and write files.. i created a script that creates a folders sub folder structure and write file from scratch. The only thing i couldn't do is write in an existing file and at certain position (like mention in question after all the import statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file line by line using `readline` module and check for particular condition to update and once all the data is read then write it into the same file using `fs` module.

index.js

```
var output = "";
var fs = require('fs');
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  if(CONDITON_TO_CHECK_FOR_UPDATE){

  }
  output += line + "\n";
});

lineReader.on('close', function (line) {
  fs.writeFile('file.txt', output, function(err, data){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});
});
```